# each query a different background-image

Tags: php, css, sql, background-image

I build this in php:

```
<?php
    $bg = array('block2.png', 'block3.png', 'block4.png', 'block5.png', 'block7.png' );
    $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1);
    $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]";
?>

<style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .block_small{
        background-image: url(/tableaux/customer/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>);
    }
    -->
</style>

<?php
    $db = new DB();
    $db->query("SELECT * FROM vestigingen ");

    while($item = $db->next_record()){
?>
        <div class="block_small">
            <img src="<?php echo $item['afbeelding']; ?>" />
            <h1><?php echo $item['plaats']; ?></h1>
            <div class="content_blocks">
                <p><?php echo $item['adres']; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $item['postcode']; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $item['telefoon']; ?></p>
                <p><?php echo $item['mail']; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="arrow"><?php echo $item['link']; ?></div>
        </div>
    <?
    }
    ?>
```

Content loads from a SQL database, I want every block to have a different background-image, now they are all the same.
I first tried to put the style in the while loop but that didn't work.
Idea's ?

Comment: can you put the code when used style in while loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the div containers to have a different background you cannot append the same class to all of them. The image in the class is chosen randomly, but afterwards the same image-background is given to all the div elements with the same class.

With only php you got two possibilities to set a different background for all of the images:

first solution:

write a loop and set the css for ids #small_block1-#small_blockx.

second solution:

set inline css for all the elements within the style tag in a loop. I will show this solution below.

```
<?php
    $bg = array('block2.png', 'block3.png', 'block4.png', 'block5.png', 'block7.png' );
    $db = new DB();
    $db->query("SELECT * FROM vestigingen ");

    $counter = 0;
    while($item = $db->next_record()){
?>
        <div class="block_small" style="background-image: url(/tableaux/customer/images/<?php echo $bg[$counter]; ?>);" >
            <img src="<?php echo $item['afbeelding']; ?>" />
            <h1><?php echo $item['plaats']; ?></h1>
            <div class="content_blocks">
            <p><?php echo $item['adres']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $item['postcode']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $item['telefoon']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $item['mail']; ?></p>
            </div>
            <div class="arrow"><?php echo $item['link']; ?></div>
        </div>
<?
    $counter++; 
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you see the original `$bg` array, it won't show the `block0`, `block1`, `block6` images, and also, if there are more then 7 items in the loop, it will fail on that. This is why OP want's to using random. But i think, he asked badly, because i think he really wants different images. Not clear to me.

Comment: it has to choose random from block2, block3, block4, block5, block6 or block 7

Comment: I did not focus on the random part. He already had a solution to take a random picture. He did not know how to display them. That's why explained that.

Answer (score 0):

You are do it in wrong way, you are always update the style. Instead of this, add an inline style.

```
<?php
$bg = array('block2.png', 'block3.png', 'block4.png', 'block5.png', 'block7.png');
$db = new DB();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM vestigingen ");
while ($item = $db->next_record()) {
    $selectedBg = $bg[array_rand($bg)];
    ?>
    <div class="block_small" style="background-image: url('/tableaux/customer/images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>)';">
        <img src="<?php echo $item['afbeelding']; ?>" />
        <h1><?php echo $item['plaats']; ?></h1>
        <div class="content_blocks">
            <p><?php echo $item['adres']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $item['postcode']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $item['telefoon']; ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $item['mail']; ?></p>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow"><?php echo $item['link']; ?></div>
    </div>

    <?php
}
```

Comment: You left off the background-image: property on your style.